# how to call javascripte funiction when user click on link or using src tag of html

Tags: javascript, html

How can we know if the user clicked on a link a minimum of 10 times or not? If user clicks 10 times on link, then open an automatic other window to accept data from user and store it.....

Please solve it using JS and HTML.

And also how can we call JS function using "src" tag of HTML?

Comment: off topic: ... why so many uppercase letters ?

Comment: "Please Solve It Using JS and HTML"? Is this homework, or are you treating SO as your personal "do-this-for-me" service?

Comment: Split this into 3 questions and ask/search for them separately: 1. *"How can I detect link clicks in JavaScript?"*, 2. *"What is a good way to keep track of clicks across visits."*, and 3. *"How do I open a popup window?"*

Comment: Voted to close for being vague and overly broad.  It is not possible to give a useful answer to the question as stated.

Comment: Thanks @Deestan For Giving Some Good Way To Ask Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link:

```
    <a onClick="doTheMagic('http://www.google.com/',1);" href="#">Click on it.</a> Your Total Clicked: <span id="timesClicked_1">0</span>; Remaining Total Clicked <span id="timesRequired_1">10</span>
    <br />
    <a onClick="doTheMagic('http://www.facebook.com/',2);" href="#">Click on it.</a> Your Total Clicked: <span id="timesClicked_2">0</span>; Remaining Total Clicked <span id="timesRequired_2">10</span>
    <br />
    <a onClick="doTheMagic('http://www.twitter.com/',3);" href="#">Click on it.</a> Your Total Clicked: <span id="timesClicked_3">0</span>; Remaining Total Clicked <span id="timesRequired_3">10</span>
```

The javascript:

```
var clickCounter = new Array();
clickCounter[1] = 0;
clickCounter[2] = 0;
clickCounter[3] = 0;

function doTheMagic(src,linkNumber){
    clickCounter[linkNumber]++;
    if(clickCounter[linkNumber] >= 10){
       poptastic(src);
    }
    document.getElementById("timesClicked_" + linkNumber).innerHTML = clickCounter[linkNumber];
    document.getElementById("timesRequired_" + linkNumber).innerHTML = (10 - clickCounter[linkNumber]);
}

var newwindow;
var adParams = {a: '9386380', size: '728x90'};
var size = adParams['size'].split("x");
function poptastic(url){
    var params = [
                'height='+size[0],
                'width='+size[1],
                'fullscreen=no' // only works in IE, but here for completeness
                ].join(',');
    newwindow=window.open(url,'name',params);
    if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ToBadForU/a9d4J/2/)

Comment: Technically correct, but I believe he wants the user to be able to navigate the link each time.

Comment: How we count only one user how much time click on link to given all links and how we display the total clicked by that user if that he Complete 10 clicked on given links to open another window to accept a some text data for him and save it.... Thanks @TWCrap

Comment: @KalpeshRajai, updated the answer totaly to fit the question better

Comment: How we apply same thing which you give me in more than 10 links or script @TWCrap

Comment: @KalpeshRajai, updated the answer and link....

Comment: If i have this type of script how to apply this thing

Comment: @KalpeshRajai, can you update your guestion with that part, so it is better readable for us...

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
var adParams = {a: '9386380', size: '728x90'};
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://cdn.adjagat.com/adjagat/scripts/smart/smart.js'></script>

Comment: @TWCrap Hello I Give You One Site Please Visit This Site:- http://putfreeadvertise.blogspot.in/

Comment: @KalpeshRajai, updated the answer... didn't know what you wanted to do with the a..

Comment: Which i give you site i put advertisement of another website now user click on advertisements than how we display a message like "Your Total Clicked:- 1" And another one "Remaining Total Clicked:- 9" If user complete 10 clicked than open one window to accept some text type data? And It Store in any location ?

Comment: @TWCrap Please Solve This Problem For Me

Comment: @KalpeshRajai, updated the answer... For hire, email difrncestick[at]gmail.com

Comment: ok @TWCrap ok For Last One When User Come My Site And Click On Ten Different Ads At That Time How We Can Show The Another Window And accept and save data.

Comment: @KalpeshRajai That is already answerd??? If not, try to describe more your question... or hire me ( difrncestick[at]gmail.com )

Comment: Hello @TWCrap i also send email on difrncestick@gmail.com. Please Check it And Give Me Answer With Example

Comment: @TWCrap, you get an upvote for being a remarkably patient person.

Comment: @Deestan, thank you verry much ^^

Comment: @TWCrap hello friend. On internet where we want store html file and user can run it free

Comment: @KalpeshRajai, i think it's better if we contineu chatting trough email. Mayby it's better if you answer the question i asked you on the mail....

Answer (score 0):

[On click event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp). Use this to catch mouse clicks and execute javascript.
Please don't use caps on Every Single Word. It makes your question hard to read.

Comment: Understatement. I'd say it makes the OP's question incredibly painful to read.

Comment: How we count only one user how much time click on link to given all links and how we display the total clicked by that user if that he Complete 10 clicked on given links to open another window to accept a some text data for him and save it.... @JamWaffles

Comment: @KalpeshRajai: take a look at the answer above: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13470983/1835379